# `TypeError: providers.forEach is not a function` with Angular2 in AOT build

Tags: angular

I searched in existing issues on ng2-bootstrap Github project, but could not find anything similar. Same here on SO.

I'm working with an Angular 2 (*2.1.0*), TypeScript 2 (*2.0.3*), Webpack 2 (*2.1.0-beta.25*) application. Build chain has both a development build and a production one, with AOT and uglifyjs. Application depends on ng2-bootstrap `TabsModule` and `DropdownModule` (*1.1.14*).

Development build goes fine. When building with AOT, that fails with:

```
TypeError: providers.forEach is not a function
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14292:21)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14051:60)
  at D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12801:47
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at analyzeModules (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12800:17)
  at OfflineCompiler.analyzeModules (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12826:18)
  at CodeGenerator.codegen (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:122:47)
  at codegen (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:7:81)
  at Object.main (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:30:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\myproj\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:14:9)
```

I tried fiddling with local copy within `node_modules\ng2-bootstrap\components`, adding a `providers: []` both in respective `xxx.module.js` and `xxx.module.metadata.js`, but with no luck. Not sure if that constitutes any proof though.

Has anyone tried with AOT and recent ng2-bootstrap versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding console logs to @angular `compiler.umd.js`, the issue came out and - I'd like to make it clear - it is *completely unrelated* to ng2-bootstrap.

After recent changes, code definining main application module changed from this:

```ts
import { appProviders } from '../app/providers';
// ...

@NgModule({
  providers: [appProviders],
  // ...
```

to this:

```ts
import { appProviders as providers } from '../app/providers';
// ...

@NgModule({
  providers,
  // ...
```

basically passing an array (wrong) instead of an array of arrays (right).

The error message does not seem so helpful to get good context of the root cause, so I'm leaving this thread here, in case it might be helpful.